# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218
```

I think everything is ok :

my form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{URL::to('/').'/cp/user/search'}}" >
```

my router:

```
Route::post('cp/user/search','Panel\UserController@usersSearch');
```

my controller :

```
public function usersSearch(Request $request)
{
    $posts = $request->input();

    var_dump($posts['fname']);

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your router be `Route::post('/cp/user/search','Panel\UserController@usersSearch');`?

Comment: No... I've been test it.

Comment: try `{{url('/cp/user/search')}}` as action

Comment: you can try either `<form method="post" action="/cp/user/search" >` or `<form method="post" action="{{ url('/cp/user/search')}}" >` and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/cp/user/search') }}" >
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem